# Ruby miscalculation of MD5 for file

Tags: ruby, md5, checksum

I am calculating a MD5 sum for a file to compare it with values supplied in a text file.  I use the following line to create the checksum:

```
cksum = File.open(File.join(File.dirname(path), file),'rb') do |f| 
  MD5.hexdigest(f.read)
end
```

Every once in a while I get one that does not match but running the md5 manually at the system level shows the file has the correct MD5.

Does anyone see any issue with the process I am using to calculate the MD5 value or have any idea why they sometimes do not match when calculated by this ruby method?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: I can not explain it.  Are there any known issues with the md5 libraries for ruby version 1.8.6?

Comment: ugh, 1.8.6. You realize it's 10 years old and is unsupported for 6 years already?

Answer (score 3):

For followers, there's also a method:

for a file: `Digest::MD5.file('filename').hexdigest`

Comment: `require 'digest'`

Answer (score 0):

At this point MD5 is a well-exercised message digest with an extensive suite of test vectors. It is *extremely* unlikely that there is an issue with Ruby's implementation of it.

It is almost certainly another explanation, such as that perhaps when your checksum executes, the file has not yet been fully written (i.e. by another process). In troubleshooting, it may be helpful to note the length of the result from `f.read` and verify that against the file size. You could even save the read contents to a separate file for later comparison when you discover a discrepancy. That could offer a clue.

You're correctly opening the file with binary mode, so that is good.